# Application Insights Dependency types

Tags: c#, .net, azure-application-insights

I just got started with Application Insights and wanted to highlight dependencies between different operations. Currently I am using this code:

```html
using (var x = telemetry.StartOperation<DependencyTelemetry>("my TEst")) {
  x.Telemetry.Type = "SQL"; 
}
```

setting the Telemetry.Type to "SQL" makes the dependency appear as SQL DB which is fine and exactly what I want.
But I could not find any information about what other "Types" are supported here and what their exact Type would be?
e.g Blob Stores? Web APIs? 
[image: AI with Icons]
thanks in advance,
-gerhard

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The are dependency types getting custom icons in Application Map:
 - SQL
 - Custom HTTP types, based on the [following criteria](https://github.com/Microsoft/ApplicationInsights-Home/wiki/Dependency-types-generated-by-AppInsights-processing-pipeline):
 1. Azure blob: when host name ends with blob.core.windows.net
 2. Azure table: when host name ends with table.core.windows.net
 3. Azure queue: when host name ends with queue.core.windows.net
 4. Web Service: when host name ends with .asmx or contains .asmx/
 5. WCF Service: when host name ends with .svc or contains .svc/
 - All other HTTP or AJAX

Going forward the list will be extended with other dependency types that will get custom item in ApplicationMap.

Comment: When the list is extended will the new types be documented somewhere?

Comment: Any updates so far?

Answer (score 7):

There's no limitation that I'm aware of.
Some dependencies are reported automatically by the SDK (such as SQL, Ajax), so these will get a pretty name in Application Map, but you can put there whatever makes sense in your application's BL.
The list of out-of-the-box dependency types Application Insights collect right now can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-insights/app-insights-asp-net-dependencies), although the documentation does not contain the dependency type string that you're interested in.
Non definitive list from my own experience:

- SQL
- HTTP
- Azure queue
- Azure table
- Azure blob
- Azure DocumentDb
- Ajax
- Redis
- Azure Service Bus
- MySQL
- Azure IoT Hub
- Azure Event Hubs

Comment: yes, I am interested in the pretty Icons in the Application Map and would like to know which Type makes it appear as SQL, which as Blob, which as Web API, etc.
is there any official list? I could not find any

Comment: Added some samples in my answer

Comment: Are there any updates to this list?  Is it posted anywhere?  p.s. looking for MongoDB

Comment: Any updates in 2023?